# Factoring a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $x+3$ and $x+4$ are both factors of the following determinant:

$\begin{vmatrix}x+4&2&3\\-1&x+1&-3\\0&2&x+7\end{vmatrix}$

I have done this by expanding the determinant, but I want to prove this without expansion. What I did so far is to replace row 1 by row 1+row 2, and this proves that$x+3$ is a factor, but I cannot seem to prove $x+4$ is a factor. Any help?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)?  Then $\det(A)=x^3 + 12x^2 + 47x + 60=(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)$ by the Rational Root Theorem. Since this is easy, it should suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that from the expression of the determinant, you can conclude that it will be a polynomial in $x$. Let us call it $D(x)$.

Now, $x + 3$ being a factor of $D(x)$ is equivalent to $D(-3) = 0$. What do you get upon substituting $x = 3$ in the determinant? Do you see that the first row is a multiple of the second?

Similarly, what is $D(-4)$? Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 2):

After what you did, multiply the 1st row by $(-1)$ and add it to the 3rd row. And you get the $(x+4)$ factor too (in the 3rd row).

In other words, subtract the 1st row from the 3rd one.